# Painting texture in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am working on a baby app and there is a Bath scene in which user applies soap to the baby's body. That is he drags the soap bar over the body like painting and soap bubbles appear on the body wherever the soap is applied like painting soap texture with a brush (soap bar).

I have the soap bar sprite and the texture sprite and the baby sprite.

How can I achieve an effect like that ?

Edit: So I have this bubbles sprite. And I want wherever the user touches, the opacity of that point in the sprite becomes 1 or 255. In start the opacity would be zero so it won't be visible and when the user drags the soap over the baby's body the opacity will become 255 for every point the user drags the soap over.

[image: Here see the soap bubbles sprite]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could achieve this the following way:

1. Place your "baby with bubbles" in a CCLayer (as a sprite).  This will be the background.
2. Create a second layer in front of the first and put a CCTexture2D into it, filled with white.
3. Whenever the user touches the screen, at that point, draw the brush sprite into the texture.  The brush sprite must draw with transparency.

[This reference may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894407/making-a-hole-on-a-ccrendertexture)

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, depends on how you want the bubbles to look like.

1. Just add a lot of soap_bubble sprite as the child node of the baby_body(or whatever node you use as parent).
   It's really easy to do and you can mess with the soap_bubble later (wash them away for example)
2. You can also generate a texture with the soap_bubbles, and put it on top of the baby. It will take a bit more effort, and [this link](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches) kind of tell you how it's done

In either case you also want a way to limit player only paint on the baby, which could be easily achieved by using hitboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd imagine that the bubbles were to "pop" sometime after applying, so you may as well try using particle effects. Particle Designer works great with cocos2d-x, unfortunatelly it is not free - [link](http://www.71squared.com/en/particledesigner)

Comment: No I don't want to use particles. Try playing Baby Care by 6677 available on Google Play. I want an effect like that.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider CCClippingNode, which uses opengl stencil buffer internally and is quite efficient. Take a look at cocos2d-x sample code for usage.